# Delete elements with highest frequency

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking at a challenge and unable to solve it:

> We are given a tube with one open end, and q queries. Each query contains 2 integers: X and N.
>
> If X=1, insert N into the tube at its open end.
>
> If X=2, take out an integer that is occurring the most (i.e., has the largest frequency in the tube), and remove its occurrence closest to the open end of the tube. If the frequency of more than one number is the same and greatest, we should remove the number closest to the open end of the tube. N is ignored in this query.
>
> Return the list of elements that are removed during the X=2 queries.
>
> #### Example input
>
> ```
> q=6
> 1,2
> 1,4
> 1,3
> 1,2
> 2,-1
> 2,-1
> ```
>
> #### Expected output
>
> ```
> [2,3]
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) of [stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), combined with a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

The array will have an entry per frequency, so that all N-values that occurred the first time will be stored in the first array entry, those N that occurred a second time will be stored in the second array entry, ...etc. In each array entry, the collected N values will be stored in order of query -- so as a stack. When an N value occurs repeatedly, their previous location will not be affected... another N-value will just be added to another stack.

The hash table will be used to track the current number of occurrences of an N value. Its key/value pairs are (N, frequency) pairs. That way we know in which substack to find/add a certain N.

The algorithm in pseudo code:

```pascal
function solve(queries)
    array ← an empty dynamic array of stacks of N-values
    freq ← an empty hashmap of (N, frequency) key/value pairs
    result ← an empty dynamic array of N-values

    for i ← 1 to length(queries) do
        x ← queries[i][1]
        n ← queries[i][2]
        if x equals 1 then
            if not freq has n then
                freq[n] ← 0
            end if
            increment freq[n]
            if freq[n] > size of array then
                append an emtpy stack to array
            end if
            push n on the stack at array[freq[n]]
        else
            stack ← last stack on array
            pop n from stack
            if stack is empty then
                pop this stack from array
            end if
            append n to result
        end if
    end for
    return result
end function
```

Implementation in Python:

```py
def solve(queries):
    buckets = [[-1]]  # entry at index 0 is not used. It is just a filler
    freq = defaultdict(int)

    for i, (x, n) in enumerate(queries):
        if x == 1:
            freq[n] += 1
            if freq[n] >= len(buckets):
                buckets.append([])
            buckets[freq[n]].append(n)
        else:
            n = buckets[-1].pop()
            if len(buckets[-1]) == 0:
                buckets.pop()
            yield n

# Demo run
queries = [(1, 2),(1, 4),(1, 3),(1, 2),(2, -1),(2, -1)]
print(*solve(queries))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above logic looks good, if someone is looking for the same solution but in java, here it is. I have added print statements and comments if someone wants to know the values of the map and set and stack in intermediate stages.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i< t; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(x == 1) {
                // map to store integer and its frequency
                map.put(n, map.getOrDefault(n, 0)+1);
                stack.add(n);
            } else {
                // System.out.println("Map: " + map);
                
                int maxFreq = 0;
                int maxElement = 0;
                for(int k: stack) {
                    if(map.get(k) > maxFreq) {
                        maxElement = k;
                        maxFreq = map.get(k);
                    }
                }
                // could be multiple values with same frequency, so keep it in a stack and check
                // from the end of the stack if any element is present in the stack
                Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
                for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e: map.entrySet()) {
                    if(e.getValue() == maxFreq) {
                        set.add(e.getKey());
                    }
                }
                // after the above loop, set will contain all elements with frequency = maxFreq
                // System.out.println("Need to remove one of " + set + " with maxFrequency " + maxFreq);
                int indexToRemove = -1;
                for(int j = stack.size()-1; j>=0; j--) {
                    if(set.contains(stack.get(j))) {
                        indexToRemove = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int num = stack.remove(indexToRemove);
                map.put(num, map.get(num) -1);
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```